# jquery - show and hide DIV with the select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, show-hide

```
<label for="continent">Select Continent</label>
<select id="continent" onchange="countryChange(this );">
    <option value="empty">Select a Continent</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
</select>
<br/>
<label for="country">Select a country</label>
<select id="country">
    <option value="0">Select a country</option>
</select>
<div id="soc-pri">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input name="customer" type="radio" value="company" />
    <label for="private">Private</label>
    <input name="customer" type="radio" value="private" />
</div>
<div id="lib-ass">
    <label for="individual firm / freelancer">Individual Firm / Freelancer Professionista</label>
    <input name="customer" type="radio" value="privato" />
    <label for="association">Associazione</label>
    <input name="customer" type="radio" value="association" />
</div>




$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        if ($("select option:selected").val() == "Europe") {
            $('#lib-ass').show();
            $('#soc-pri').show();

        } else if ($("select option:selected").val() != "Europe") {
            $('#lib-ass').hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Hello everyone, I just started to study jquery. 
I have two select fields that contain the continents and countries.

My needs nascodere show the two-DIV, "lib-ass" and "soc-first":

1) When you select the continent of Europe the DIV "lib-ass," appears. **That is OK**

2) When you do not select the continent Europe DIV "lib-ass", hides. **That is OK**

3 When you do not select the country DIV Britain the "lib-ass" must hide. **This is not OK**.

When you select the country DIV Britain the "lib-ass" you have to show. **This is not OK**

My problem is that I can not hide-show, when you select your country Britain the DIV tag with id "lib-ass."

Where am I wrong?

I hope averdato much information as possible. 
thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/carmy/jg7Ls/6/

Comment: What does `My needs nascodere` mean?

Comment: Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jg7Ls/7/)

Comment: sorry for the bad English

Comment: I wanted to write hide, excuse me

Comment: it @Satpal is what I managed to do

Comment: @j08691 I wanted to write hide, excuse me

Comment: You "wanted to write hide" where? To make corrections, please edit the question rather than commenting (click the grey "edit" link under the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/J2XDk/1/ Is this what you're looking to do?

I made a few changes: `select` values can be retrieved by calling `.val()` directly on the select (no need for finding the selected option). I also look it up specifically using the select box ID since just doing `$('select')` is ambiguous.  Save values to variables so you don't have to execute the jQuery multiple times. The alternate condition for the Europe check can just use else, no need to specifically check for `!= "Europe"`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("select").change(function () {
        var continent = $('#continent').val(),
            country = $('#country').val(),
            $libass = $('#lib-ass'),
            $socpri = $('#soc-pri');

        if (continent === "Europe") {
            $libass.show();
            $socpri.show();

        } else {
            $libass.hide();
        }

        if(country === 'Britain') {
            $libass.hide();                
        } else {
            $libass.show();   
        }

    }).change();
});
```

Comment: It was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your logic:

```
$("#country").change(function(){
            if($("#country option:selected").val() == "Britain") {
                $('#lib-ass').show(); 
                $('#soc-pri').show();
            }else{
                $('#lib-ass').hide();
            }
 }).change();
```

Where country is the select box of your selected country. The hashtag (#) is used to call a specific ID in Jquery.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jg7Ls/8/)

Comment: I do not know, I just joined, I'm sorry

Comment: Don't worry! You can just accept an answer when you believe it fits your requirements.